# Cannot retrieve and install ejabberd contribution modules

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I have installed ejabberd 16.03 from binary source (ejabberd-16.03-osx-installer.app.zip)

My os is OS X Yosemite

After installation completed I started ejabberd:

```
cd ejabberd_directory/bin

./ejabberdctl start
```

I even checked the status to make sure it is started. Then I tried to retrieve the list of available modules:

```
./ejabberdctl modules_update_specs
```

and it says ok!

But I get nothing by running this:

```
./ejabberdctl modules_available
```

And I cannot install any module.

I would appreciate any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

```
./ejabberdctl modules_update_specs
```

this command creates an empty folder ~/.ejabberd_modules/sources

```
cd ~/.ejabberd_modules/sources
git clone https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib.git
```

and then you get module list and install them:

```
./ejabberdctl modules_available
```

But keep in mind that running ./ejabberdctl modules_update_specs will empty your sources folder and delete the modules.

Answer (score 1):

Github made some changes and we have to adapt the code to be able to install modules again. You will need ejabberd 16.06 to use this feature.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what changes the github made? And which file should we look for the code related to module_available commands?